# Error while plotting line chart from JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

While creating a fiddle, I wasnt able to plot the line chart using the data which was previously into `.json` file. I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

The chart can be plotted if the JSON is external provided I use `d3.json()`. 
How do I get [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/SKb8W/1/) working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `d3.json()`. It was making HTTP request.

http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/SKb8W/2/